# redisgraph-bulk-loader issues with huge data in csv file

Tags: redis, load-csv, redisgraph

Below are the few issues I am getting when I am trying to upload a file with around one million records. Help me on resolving the issues. When I am try to find the solution in blogs, all are suggesting to modify some logic. But I am using redisgraph-bulk-loader utility directly.

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 3565: invalid continuation byte

_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte

Not working if column value contains quotes and comma.

redisgraph_bulk_loader.bulk_insert.CSVError: /home/ec2-user/test.csv:2 Expected 4 columns, encountered 5 ('1,3,4,"5,6"')

GraphName should be unique always for each new upload. In this case, if I want to add some more nodes to same graph or if I want establish relationships from some other file how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered in the issue you opened on the [redisgraph-bulk-loader repository](https://github.com/RedisGraph/redisgraph-bulk-loader/issues/28):

> Not working if column value contains quotes and comma.

This may be resolvable by using the `--quote` argument to change input-quoting behavior. The next suggestion would render this unnecessary, however.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 3565: invalid continuation byte
>   _csv.Error: line contains NULL byte

These may also be problems with type inference logic. You may wish to try using an updated branch (to be merged soon) that introduces enforced schema; this will solve your first problem as well.
`git checkout improve-loader-logic`
And updated your header rows as described in [the updated branch's docs](https://github.com/RedisGraph/redisgraph-bulk-loader/tree/improve-loader-logic#input-schemas).

If this does not resolve your issues, you may need to look deeper into encoding problems.

> GraphName should be unique always for each new upload. In this case, if I want to add some more nodes to same graph or if I want establish relationships from some other file how to achieve this.

The bulk loader is a one-time tool, and currently all updates to existing graphs must be made using Cypher queries.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected my file according to the python logic inside the program to run successfully. It is working now.

Comment: Issue details updated at github. Can you please check once

https://github.com/RedisGraph/redisgraph-bulk-loader/issues/28